# using "if" on a time literal (formatting help)

Tags: c#

I have a time object which if null is for some reason interpreted as `00:00:00`. So I need to do a test if it is null, but now I can't do that so I need the equivalent of:

```
if (TimeObject == 00:00:00) {...
```

What would the format for this if statement be?

Comment: Can you include the definition of your TimeObject?

Comment: What is this "time" object?  If it's a `System.DateTime`, I doubt very much it has a value of "00:00:00".

Comment: There are no `DateTime` literals in C# (yet).

Comment: If your `TimeObject` *is null*, then a simple `TimeObject == null` should work. If it's "interpreted" (by whom?) as `00:00:00` then it's probably not null. But what is `TimeObject` anyway?

Comment: If you time object is of type `System.TimeSpan` you could probably check `TimeObject == TimeSpan.Zero`

Comment: yes it is a timespan object and timespan.zero works. thanks!  I will however change it to a nullable type as was suggested below as that would suit my purposes better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, C# does not support time literals, so `00:00:00` won't make sense to a standard C# compiler.

Second, in order to handle time, you will need to use [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) structures.

Third, because these are structures, they can never be `null` - they have a `default` value, but will not allow `DateTime dt = null;` If you want a nullable struct, use [Nullable Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) (thus `DateTime?` and `TimeSpan?`)

Comment: Thanks I will change it to a nullable type.

Comment: If TimeObject is just a struct, then surely comparing it to `new TimeObject()`, omitting any parameters will do the job you are hoping to? I'd still make it nullable, but just in case you didn't have access to the DatTime code for whatever reason.

Comment: yes, comparing a struct to `new ___()` will work, but can be misleading to read, which is why I prefer `default(___)`. `DateTime` is a part of the .NET Framework - of you don't have access to it, you're using an implementation of C# you should specify in the question.

Comment: Honestly didn't even know about default, thanks for that comment.